# Updating to Angular 9 httpclient and rxjs type errors

Tags: angular, rxjs

Update: Discovered it's an issue with angular libraries so this question is now more about how to explicitly point to the right nnoe_modules folder

I'm a little stumped with updating this angular code seems to be getting type errors after updating to the latest via ng update

```
  protected get(endPoint: string, params: Params = {}): any {
    return this.http.get(endPoint, { params }).pipe(
      this.handleRetry,
      tap((_) => this.log(`fetched data`)),
      catchError(this.handleError<any>('getList', []))
    );
  }
```

receive this error, but am not sure how to fix the types, even tried spamming  everywhere

TS2345: Argument of type 'MonoTypeOperatorFunction' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction<unknown, unknown>'.
Types of parameters 'source' and 'source' are incompatible.

package.json looks like this

```
"@angular/animations": "~9.1.2",
"@angular/cdk": "^9.2.1",
"@angular/common": "~9.1.2",
"@angular/compiler": "~9.1.2",
"@angular/core": "~9.1.2",
"@angular/flex-layout": "^9.0.0-beta.29",
"@angular/forms": "~9.1.2",
"@angular/material": "^9.2.1",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^9.1.2",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~9.1.2",
"@angular/router": "~9.1.2",
"@ng-select/ng-select": "^4.0.0",
"@ngx-formly/core": "^5.5.15",
"@ngx-formly/material": "^5.5.15",
"@ngx-formly/schematics": "^5.6.0",
"keycloak": "^1.2.0",
"keycloak-angular": "^7.2.0",
"keycloak-js": "^9.0.3",
"ngx-permissions": "^7.0.3",
"rxjs": "~6.5.5",
"zone.js": "~0.10.2"
```

EDIT: to clarify I'm working in a angular library the project I'm building is throwing the error looks like it can't find the right node_modules, I noticed this when looking at a version mismatch in this build error the versions are up to date but the problem isn't solved

Types of parameters 'source' and 'source' are incompatible.
Type 'import("C:/repos/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Observable").Observable' is not assignable to type 'import("C:/repos/projects/core-ui/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Observable").Observable'.

not sure why it's using both versions.

Comment: _"Discovered it's an issue with angular libraries so this question is now more about how to explicitly point to the right node_modules folder"_ - can you clarify?

Comment: sure I've edited my question with more details

Comment: The module resolution algorithm does a recursive upward walk of the directory tree looking for `node_modules` directories. Your repos dir has a `node_modules` directly within it. For whatever reason, a (possibly transitive) dependency is not present in your `core-ui/node_modules` dir. You should remove `repos/node_modules`.

Comment: thanks, I did the other way where the main project package as the node_modules installed and removed node_modules from the sub project, probably need to iron this out better but have a CI/CD pipeline to cinsider. If you want to put your comment into an answer I will accept it for the karma :)

Comment: I didn't realize your projects were intentionally nested. There are different solutions for such a situation but I'm glad to have been of assistance.